# How to handle print window in test cafe?

Tags: testcafe

User clicks a button and it opens another browser window with a document preview and immediately the print dialog is also opened. How can this be handled in the test? I looked at [setNativeDialogHandler](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402684/reference/test-api/testcontroller/setnativedialoghandler) method, however it isn't obvious how to write script in test cafe in that case. Can please anybody advise?

Answer (score 0):

This capability is available in TestCafe v3.0.0. Please update your TestCafe version or add the following code to [clientScript](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402843/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts):

```js
window.print = function () {};
```